# Unwind inside lookup in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 entities to merge: **Customer** and **Feedback**. Feedback contains an embedded array of upvotes (**Upvote**)

A customer is not able to upvote more than once for a specific feedback.
What I would like to achieve is - given a specific feedback id - get the complete list of customers with an additional virtual attribute that states whether he/she upvoted the given feedback.

```
Customer.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $match: { company_id: new ObjectID(req.user.company_id) }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'feedbacks',
          let: { 'c_id': '$_id' },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $unwind: '$upvotes'
            },
            {
              $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$upvotes.customer_id._id', '$$c_id'] } }
            }
          ],
          as: 'upvotes'
        }
      }
    ],
    function(err, customers) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send(err);
      } else {
        res.send({ customers });
      }
    }
  );
```

To do that I have to look through the list of upvotes for that specific feedback and, then, join it with the customer table using the customer_id.

The above mentioned approach does not work. Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Sample data (Feedback)

```
{
        "size": 0,
        "points": 50,
        "status": "open",
        "potential": 0,
        "real": 5000,
        "_id": "5c3d033271ceb7edc37d156c",
        "title": "Custom Invoice Templates",
        "description": "Provide an editor to create custom invoices.",
        "owner_id": {
            "_id": "5c3b684f7cec8be977c2a465",
            "email": "maurizio@acme.com"
        },
        "company_id": "5c3b684f7cec8be977c2a462",
        "project_id": "5c3b68507cec8be977c2a468",
        "upvotes": [
            {
                "_id": "5c3fa5b371ceb7edc37d159a",
                "comments": "bbbb",
                "priority": "should",
                "customer_id": {
                    "size": 0,
                    "potential": 0,
                    "real": 5000,
                    "_id": "5c3b68507cec8be977c2a485",
                    "name": "Oyomia Ltd."
                },
                "owner_id": {
                    "_id": "5c3b684f7cec8be977c2a465",
                    "email": "maurizio@acme.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "updatedAt": "2019-01-16T21:44:19.215Z",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-14T21:46:26.286Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Sample data (Customer)

```
{
        "size": 0,
        "potential": 0,
        "real": 5000,
        "_id": "5c3b68507cec8be977c2a485",
        "name": "Oyomia Ltd.",
        "contact": {
            "_id": "5c40f8de71ceb7edc37d15ab",
            "name": "Nick Page",
            "email": "np@oyoma.com"
        },
        "company_id": "5c3b684f7cec8be977c2a462",
        "deals": [
            {
                "value": 5000,
                "_id": "5c3b68507cec8be977c2a487",
                "name": "Armour batch",
                "status": "won",
                "type": "non_recurring",
                "updatedAt": "2019-01-13T16:33:20.870Z"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0,
        "updatedAt": "2019-01-17T21:51:26.877Z"
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue in above query? Could you show some sample data

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet added sample data

Comment: One reason my be because `upvotes.customer_id._id` is not an `objectId` and the second is `from` expression of `$lookup` should be `feedbacks` not `feedback`

Comment: why feedbacks? the entity is called feedback and is an object not an array. How would query for upvotes.customer_id._id otherwise?

Comment: because mongoose pluralize the collection name at the time of creation that's why `feedbacks`.

Comment: See here it is working https://mongoplayground.net/p/-6nsgsV2IxP

Comment: It does not really work as expected though. I only wanted to join upvotes with customers. Now, it seems i have a strange recurring data structure inside.

Comment: What is not working? I can see the join data inside upvotes key

Comment: the join is done between Customers and Feedbacks, but I thought that with unwind I could make the join between Customers and Upvotes (which is what I want to achieve)